# Parsing custom XAML-like document to C# equivalent? (Or binaries)

Tags: c#, parsing, xaml, xna

I'm working on an XNA project, for the Xbox 360.

For this I have built an extensive UI library, all with relative positions, dozens of controls and stuff like that.

At the moment of speaking, all the design elements are created in page classes, which is a lot of code (think of margins, aligns, labels, and so on).

So I was thinking, shouldn't it be possible, to create a file, like a XAML file for example, and using C#, parse it to objects?

XNAML uses this kind of approach (I think), so I know it must be possible, I'm just wondering how. I could go with the approach of parsing the file manually line by line, and creating every object, but I think this would be pretty complex & nasty code, considering the amount of different objects. Any input is greatly appreciated!

F.Y.I., XNAML is deprecated (I even think it never went live)

Comment: A paste of some of your custom code might help. Depending on the structure it might not be too hard to do programatically. Like, if you had "<Button Name="b1" Width=".3" Height=".1" Center=".5, .5"/> you could parse starting at '<', split by ' ', then parse each argument: create a Button, store it in a UI dictionary with key "b1", give it a width of .3, height of .1 and center of new Vector2(.5, .5). A bit trickier to do nested stuff, though, but all very possible. There's plenty of resources for reading text files by line in C#.

Comment: This article gives a decent explanation of how to parse xaml and create controls, all in 300 lines of code. http://xaml.sourceforge.net/mycroxaml.html